# Resizing components in Material UI without deformatting

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-typescript

I have been trying to resize a select component from material UI. The problem that arrised was the fact that I could not resize the component properly with the help of the className property, the label was not in the right place and the selection shade height was greater than the one from the select box I resized (height: 24px). This is what i tried:

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label">Age</InputLabel>
    <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
        id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
        value={age}
        onChange={handleChange}
        label="Age"
        className={classes.MuiSelect}

    >
        <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

And this was the makestyles I used:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        formControl: {
            margin: theme.spacing(1),
            minWidth: 120,
        },
        selectEmpty: {
            marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
        },
        MuiSelect: {

            width: "338px",
            height: "24px"

        }
    }),
);
```

The link to the sandbox with the example: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-ds9s6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Finally, this was the result:

[Box with the label in the wrong place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmLU2.png)

[The shade of the selection is bigger than the actual box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJtDy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have changed the size of the select element, you should also modify the `.MuiInputLabel-outlined` of the related `InputLabel` element, as well as the `MuiSelect-outlined` to fit the shadows of the select box to its width and height [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-f7zol?file=/demo.tsx:7295-8091)

First please add these `outlined` and `selectOutlined` objects to the `useStyles`

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    formControl: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      minWidth: 120
    },
    selectEmpty: {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    MuiSelect: {
      width: "338px",
      height: "24px"
    },
    outlined: {
      transform: "translate(4px, 3px)"
    },
    selectOutlined: {
      padding: "0px 14px"
    }
  })
);
```

And then add them to the `InputLabel` and `Select` elements

```
<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel
          className={classes.outlined}
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
        >
          Age
        </InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-outlined-label"
          id="demo-simple-select-outlined"
          value={age}
          onChange={handleChange}
          label="Age"
          classes={{
            root: classes.MuiSelect,
            outlined: classes.selectOutlined
          }}
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
            <em>None</em>
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
```

Comment: thank you for your quick feedback. It solved the problem with the label, however when a item is selected the shadow it creates is bigger than the selection box (the shadow having 56px height and the selection box having 24px as height)

Comment: I edited the answer. Think it should solve your problems now. Please check it and let me know.